# Windows Sockets understanding recv and send

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I got a little confusion here, say I do this:

`send(serverSocks, "Size: 1348", strlen("Size: 1348"), 0)`

And then Followed by this:

`send(serverSocks, "SomeDataThatIs1348LongAndThatNeedsToBeSent", strlen("SomeDataThatIs1348LongAndThatNeedsToBeSent"), 0)`

Since they are sent consecutively, there's a chance that I'll receive it in only one piece when I do something like:

`recv(clientSocks, buf, 2000, 0)`

Right?

How am I gonna receive it from the server side? 
Or do I even need the client to send the Size first to the server? Or I could receive the whole data without even knowing the size?

EDIT:

Maybe I need to make my question clearer. How am I gonna tell that this data is a part of this first (or second) data that was sent by the client?

Comment: Is it a `TCP` socket? `send(serverSocks, "Size: 1348", strlen("File Size: 1348", 0)` doesn't make sense. If you could make that compile, it'd be undefined behaviour since you'll be reading in memory after the string literal `Size: 1348`.

Comment: Yes, it is a tcp socket, and I edited the code, sorry.

Comment: Should I use sizeof() ? Edit: I edited the code again, sorry.

Comment: TCP is a streaming protocol. If you want more structure than "a sequence of octets",  you need to implement your own protocol on top of it.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, what if I do like, "Client: The Size is This" -> "Server: Acknowledge" -> "Client: Sending Data". This way, I could make sure that all messages sent by the client is a part of another message. Ai

Comment: You don't need to send an ACK. Just send the size using `htonl` and then the data. `uint32_t size = htonl(strlen(str)); send(socket, &size, sizeof(size), 0);`, On the receiving side, use `ntohl` to get the size back.

Answer (score 1):

> Since they are sent consecutively, there's a chance that I'll receive it in only one piece when I do something like:
>
> recv(clientSocks, buf, 2000, 0)
>
> Right?

Yes.

> How am I gonna receive it from the server side?

You must frame each message in such a way that the receiver knows where one message ends and next begins. You can either:

1. Send a message's length before sending the message's data. The receiver can then read the length first, then read the specific number of bytes that follow the length.
2. Append a unique delimiter at the end of each message, something that will never appear in the message data itself, such as an ETX byte, a null terminator, a line break, etc. The receiver can then read bytes until it reaches the delimiter.

> Or do I even need the client to send the Size first to the server? Or I could receive the whole data without even knowing the size?

TCP is a streaming transport, it has no concept of message boundaries, so you must handle this in the transmitted data itself.